# Dynamically extract part of string (using R)

Tags: r, string, dynamic, split

Dears,
Please help me find a way to dynamically extract part of string value.
I have a column that contains user cases numbers assigned to a user. Every value in this column is a string, and case numbers are separated by comma. Length of string varies greatly between rows depending on total number of cases listed.
The desired outcome for me is to have one row per one case number. So, I created duplicated rows according to number of cases in Each row (3 cases = 3 identical rows, 5 cases = 5 identical rows, etc.).
Now I'm trying to only leave 1 unique case number per each row.
This is where I'm stuck. :-)
Below is the example data and desired outcome.
Thank you in advance to your assistance!

```
## generate example data
ex <- data.frame( cbind(
  cases = c("a1,ab2,abc3","a1,ab2,abc3","a1,ab2,abc3","kl2,klm3","kl2,klm3","wx2,x1,wxy3,wxyz4","wx2,x1,wxy3,wxyz4","wx2,x1,wxy3,wxyz4","wx2,x1,wxy3,wxyz4"),
  totake = c(1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3,4)
  ) )

## UPDATED
## changed to dataframe
## desired output - 3rd column with 1 case per row according to "totake" number
des <- data.frame( cbind(
  cases = c("a1,ab2,abc3","a1,ab2,abc3","a1,ab2,abc3","kl2,klm3","kl2,klm3","wx2,x1,wxy3,wxyz4","wx2,x1,wxy3,wxyz4","wx2,x1,wxy3,wxyz4","wx2,x1,wxy3,wxyz4"),
  totake = c(1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3,4),
out = c("a1","ab2","abc3","kl2","klm3","wx2","x1","wxy3","wxyz4") ) )
```

I tried Regex and sapply with strsplit, but can't seem to be able to dynamically pass the number of the string part to take for a certain row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but I'd assume `totake` controls which element of each row is selected, even though the ordering and pattern in example data seems to enable some shortcuts.

`\(totake, case) expression` is an anonymous function, a shorthand for `function(totake, case) expression`.

```r
extr <- function(m) mapply(\(totake, case) case[as.integer(totake)], 
                           m[,"totake"], 
                           strsplit(m[,"cases"], ","))

cbind(ex, out = extr(ex))
#>   cases               totake out    
#> 1 "a1,ab2,abc3"       "1"    "a1"   
#> 2 "a1,ab2,abc3"       "2"    "ab2"  
#> 3 "a1,ab2,abc3"       "3"    "abc3" 
#> 1 "kl2,klm3"          "1"    "kl2"  
#> 2 "kl2,klm3"          "2"    "klm3" 
#> 1 "wx2,x1,wxy3,wxyz4" "1"    "wx2"  
#> 2 "wx2,x1,wxy3,wxyz4" "2"    "x1"   
#> 3 "wx2,x1,wxy3,wxyz4" "3"    "wxy3" 
#> 4 "wx2,x1,wxy3,wxyz4" "4"    "wxyz4"

# with reversed rows to illustrate the effect
# of row order on output
ex_rev <- ex[9:1,1:2]
cbind(ex_rev, out = extr(ex_rev))
#>   cases               totake out    
#> 4 "wx2,x1,wxy3,wxyz4" "4"    "wxyz4"
#> 3 "wx2,x1,wxy3,wxyz4" "3"    "wxy3" 
#> 2 "wx2,x1,wxy3,wxyz4" "2"    "x1"   
#> 1 "wx2,x1,wxy3,wxyz4" "1"    "wx2"  
#> 2 "kl2,klm3"          "2"    "klm3" 
#> 1 "kl2,klm3"          "1"    "kl2"  
#> 3 "a1,ab2,abc3"       "3"    "abc3" 
#> 2 "a1,ab2,abc3"       "2"    "ab2"  
#> 1 "a1,ab2,abc3"       "1"    "a1"
```

Example data:

```r
ex <- cbind(
  cases = c("a1,ab2,abc3","a1,ab2,abc3","a1,ab2,abc3","kl2,klm3","kl2,klm3","wx2,x1,wxy3,wxyz4","wx2,x1,wxy3,wxyz4","wx2,x1,wxy3,wxyz4","wx2,x1,wxy3,wxyz4"),
  totake = c(1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3,4)
)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Yes, "totake" is designed to control which part of "cases" string to take.
So, I'm looking to have 3rd column with 1 unrepeating case number per row taken from "cases" according to its' position ("totake") inside "cases" string value.

Comment: @ArtemYan ,  then you might want to update your example data so it wouldn't follow that exact pattern, currently one can ignore `totake` column and still end up with desired output. For example something like `totake = c(3,1,2,1,2,4,2,3,1)`  with the corresponding output.

Comment: You are right. Updated. But the pattern is not a problem, it's correct. I mean, the real data does have the same pattern.
I tried to apply your solution to my original data, but somehow I get:  "Error in strsplit(m[, "Case"], ",") : non-character argument". Which is weird as "Case" column has character datatype.

Comment: Could you please explain your solution, as I feel that it's the closest to what I need.
I know that mapply accepts a function and set of arguments separated by commas. Which makes this part "\(totake, case) case[as.integer(totake)]" a function?

Comment: Updated. `\(x,y) x+y` is anonymous function shorthand,  same as `function(x ,y) x + y` . It was introduced in R 4.1 together with native pipes (`|>`) . Regarding example data in question, it is correct but with this particular pattern and ordering it also allows shortcuts that most likely will not work with your real data; that's what I tried to point out with that extra test with reversed rows.

Answer (score 1):

```
ex[, "cases"] |>
  strsplit(",") |> 
  unlist() |>
  unique()
# [1] "a1"    "ab2"   "abc3"  "kl2"   "klm3"  "wx2"   "x1"    "wxy3"  "wxyz4"
```

Comment: Thank you for a fast answer! Could you please explain what is this thing you used: |> ?

Comment: It's a pipe, `x |> foo() |> bar()` is another way of writing `bar(foo(x))`. So you could rewrite my answer as `unique(unlist(strplit(ex[, "cases"], ",")))`.

Comment: I thought pipes look like "%>%". But it doesn't matter, as unfortunately I've mislead you with my desired output. I need an extra column, not a vector. And value in this extra column should be determined by number in "totake".
I updated the question.
It would be great if you could look at my problem again, when you have a moment.

Comment: The `magrittr` pipe is `%>%`. R version 4.1.0 introduced `|>` as a dependency-free pipe built in to base R.

Answer (score 1):

```r
unlist(strsplit(ex[ex[, "totake"] == 1, "cases"], ","))
# [1] "a1"    "ab2"   "abc3"  "kl2"   "klm3"  "wx2"   "x1"    "wxy3"  "wxyz4"
```